# how to solve the session and local storage issue in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

Here I have local and session storage for loginpage.After logged in,If I change the user crediantails in application tab in console,I can able to see the existing is changing.So the session and local storages will not be changed If I change in appalication tab in console window.Any possible way other than this.

Here is my code:

```
if (isNaN(response)) {
    var login= $window.sessionStorage.getItem("login ");
    if (loginType == "DT") {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(response));
        $('#signin').modal('hide');                       
    }
    else {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(response));
        $window.location.href = "/dashboard.html";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding on your question. You want to restrict the user to change the sessionStorage or localStorage data.

**Answer :**

You can't restrict. We can not prevent a user to access a resource on his own system or machine.

**Other work around :**

- You can create a `service` to `set` and `get` the data between the controllers and then inject that service in the controller function where you want to use it.
- Store the critical data into `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` in `encrypted form` so that if user want to try to change the data. he will not able to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I think it helps for me,but how to encrypt the session storage.Can you please help for this issue.

Comment: You can use angular `$cryptogrpahy` service for that. Please mark this answer as correct if you feel suitable so that it will be useful for others user as well.

Comment: Iam unable to implement the $cryptography for th above code,can you please help me.

Comment: Try these links https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography and http://phpflow.com/misc/angular/encryption-decryption-using-crypto-js-in-angularjs/

Comment: 'Store the data in encrypted form so that if user want to try to change the data. he will not able to do that'. What part of encrypting the data disallows a user from changing it?

Comment: @pbsbr Why unchecked the answer ?

Comment: @PrajeethEmanuel we can encrypt the critical data while storing into the localStorage and decrypt while getting it back from the sessionStorage.

Comment: @Rohit That's not the point. If a user goes into the application tab and changes the encrypted data, the client will still send wrong data to the server. Both localStorage and sessionStorage are editable fields. I don't understand the point of encrypting a non-sensical access key. If a user goes through the effort of changing it, then your server should be capable of denying him/her access. There is no client-side check possible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. 
Data stored in localStorage has no expiration time.

Depending on your app session type (persistent login or session login), pick a storage type.

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if a user bothers to change his/her accessKey from the application tab to an invalid one, you should provide an option on page load to empty the userDetails object in the local/sessionStorage and reload the page.